# Graphics card and Power supply for architecture and 3d Modeling

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, motherboard, memory, power-supply

I have a friend who is an architect and now is looking to build 3d models.
He needs a new pc for fast 3d rendering and architecture related work.

Here is a list of components that I recommended.

- Intel Core I5 7600 7th Gen processor LGA 1151 socket 3.5Ghz
- Corsair Vengeance 8GB DDR4 LPX 2400MHz C16 RAM Kit for X99 Chipset (CMK8GX4M1A2400C16R)
- Gigabyte GA-H110M-S2 LGA 1151 6th Gen F20
- HDD Seagate
- WD Green 120GB Internal Solid State Drive
- Corsair Carbide Series CC-9011050
- Corsair CP-9020098-UK VS Series VS650 650 Watt
- FAN Cooler Master Hyper 212X
- Zotac GeForce GTX 1050 Ti OC Edition ZT-P10510B-10L 4GB PCI Express Graphics Card

**Will this be a good pc form him to work on**

Is the graphics card suitable for 3d work?
Is the power supply overkill with 650W or should I go with 450W?

Do mention if you have any recommendation of other products.

Comment: What does "Fast 3D rendering" constitute? What programs are they using? What's the size of their models? What's their budget?

Comment: @JMY1000 buget is about $200. Mostly will be using 3dsMax. Fast rendering means that there should not be any lag while working and moving objects on screen.

Comment: ...$200 or $2000? How many polys is he working with? What constitutes "working and moving objects"–just manipulating wireframes, or dealing with complicated materials and physics? Render times?

Comment: the budget is ~$200. The main job is to render out 3d building elevations. The rendering process can take longer but the working and manipulating should be smooth. There is nothing too complex as an architect he needs to create 3d elevation images.

Comment: The build you made isn't a $200 build, not even close–even very roughly, that build it at least $600. If you want to do something reasonable at that price point, you're going to need to go with used components. I still would like to know how many polys they're working with roughly.

Comment: I mean the budget $200 was for graphics card only. I have rest of the components figured out. Need a ~$200 graphics card that will make lag-less editing of 3d architecture models.

Comment: I think with some rebalancing you might be better served by a different computer altogether. What's your total budget? Also, I still need to know the size of the models being worked with here–how many polys, material types, etc.

Comment: Somewhere, with the likes of 100+ objects. Total budget is ~600 dollars

Comment: Would used hardware be okay?

Comment: @JMY1000 yes just need compatibility info